# C# Аргументы командной строки

Tags: c#, командная-строка, аргументы

Всем привет!
На данный момент на проекте имеется ряд аргументов при запуске приложения (visualstudio), все они выглядят довольно печально, т.е не совсем понятно кто что делает, просто набор аргументов через пробел, я бы хотел все это красиво оформить по ключам:
Вот как есть сейчас - [аргумент] [аргумент] [аргумент]...
Как хотел бы сделать - [ключ]: [аргумент]

[image: Как есть на данный момент]

Скрин выше, что имею на данный момент.
Подскажите документацию или какой-нибудь пример того, как это можно реализовать.

Comment: Возьмите какую-нибудь готовую библиотеку

Comment: Документации нет, кто как хочет - тот так и делает. Пример на 25к строк: https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline Простых примеров нет, пока вы сами не определитесь со всеми правилами, как будете передавать аргументы. PS кавычки - ЗЛО.

Answer (score 1):

То что вы хочете реализовать это похоже на INI файл. Если вам нужно передать параметры в проект но у вас их много, лучше использую файл конфигураций (мне по душе XML).

Создали файл, считали в новом проекте и удалили файл (не обязательно создавать файл на жестком диске). Можете просто всегда держать файл в AppData/Local/{своя папка}/{свой файл} и читать при открытии.

Если же у вас данных фиксированное кол-во вы можете сделать как Windows по ключам /k будет означать какой-то определенный параметр.

Comment: Во-первых, автору нужны именно аргументы командной строки. Во-вторых, даже если взять INI, то вопрос в следующем: как получить пары ключ-значение, как распарсить этот формат?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov 1. Он не уточнил что только аргументы, может он готов принять и другие варианты, я всего лишь дал информацию где он может выбрать что-то, что может ему помочь
2. Ключ и секция в них статична и она меняться не будет, а вот с распарсиванием будут трудности. Ну опять же он должен понимать что в них записано, ведь он и записывал их